# How to filter a data frame with conditions?

Tags: r

I want to filter a data frame base on the value of one column.

If A column contains value `123`, then pick those rows out, and then filter `C = 1`; if A column does not contains `123`, then pick those rows out, and then filter `D = 0`.

Here is the test df:

```
Book1 <- data.frame(
  'A' = c(123, 5, 6, 12, 445, 123),
  'B' = c(4, 56, 77, 1, 2, 3),
  'C' = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0),
  'D' = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0)
)
```

Although I can generate 2 results:

```
library(tidyverse)
Book1 %>% 
  filter(A == 123) %>% 
  filter(C == 1)

Book1 %>% 
  filter(A != 123) %>% 
  filter(D == 0)
```

Then use `rbind()` to yield the result:

```
    A  B C D
1 123  4 1 1
2   5 56 1 0
3   6 77 0 0
```

However, can someone teach me how to use maybe `filter`, `if_else` to have the same result?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `&`(and) and `|`(or) do differentiate between your conditions, i.e.

```
filter(Book1, (A == 123 & C == 1) | (A != 123 & D == 0))
#    A  B C D
#1 123  4 1 1
#2   5 56 1 0
#3   6 77 0 0
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do

```
library(dplyr)

Book1 %>%
  filter(if_else(A == 123, C == 1, D == 0))

#    A  B C D
#1 123  4 1 1
#2   5 56 1 0
#3   6 77 0 0
```

which can also be done in base R

```
Book1[with(Book1, ifelse(A == 123, C == 1, D == 0)), ]
```

Answer (score 1):

just a slightly different syntax (without `with` as suggested by @Ronak Shah):

```
 Book1[ifelse(Book1$A == 123, Book1$C == 1, Book1$D == 0), ]
```

Comment: I don't think this qualifies as a new answer.